# Avoid looping bottleneck inside cg shader

Tags: colors, shader, fragment-shader, cg

I have an issue with Cg shaders.

I'm using a shader to display a heatmap, so it modifies the color of an area of the screen based on how distant it is from the center. The problem is that if I need to color many areas, say passing 300 points, the fragment needs to loop through all of the visible screen too many times, in this case 1920x1080x300, which is obviously a bottleneck, is there a way to only tell my shader the area to color without making it loop?

```
half4 frag(vertOutput output) : COLOR 
        {
            half h = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < _Points_Length; i ++)
            {
                half dist = distance(output.worldPos, _Points[i].xyz);//_Points[i].xyz is the point I'm passing to my shader
                half radi = _Properties[i].x; //this is the radius of the area around the actual point
                half hi = 1 - saturate(dist / radi);
                h += hi * _Properties[i].y; //Properties[i].y is just an intensity modifier
            }

            h = saturate(h);
            half4 color = tex2D(_HeatTex, fixed2(h, 0.5));
            return color;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With minimum effort you could just render this into a texture at a fraction of the size. It seems to be purely visual, and likely to be low frequency and continuous so it should upscale nicely (considering you have nice details to blend with at full res). Worse case you need a slightly better upsampling method.

You could also look into using cheaper instructions, like computing using square distance and turning that radius divide into a multiply by passing the inverse.

**But** the bottom line here is that you are essentially rendering an additive particle system in the most expensive way :) You could do just that : update a particle system CPU side (or do a mesh on the fly, or do gpu instancing of a quad), precompute distance into a texture and pass intensity as colors, render into texture (downsized or not). Bim ! Use rasterizing for what it's good at :)